# GroupBy for JavaPairRDD in spark programming

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a table in Cassandra as below:

```
name       | region | year | business | subscriber | transaction
------------+--------+------+----------+------------+-------------
 Madagascar |    OMG | 2008 |     1000 |      10000 |        1000
 Madagascar |    OMG | 2009 |     1200 |      12000 |        1200
```

I want to extract the data via Spark.

How can I apply a GROUP BY query, while formatting the output similar to the example below?

```
{"name":"country1",
"region":"asia",
"transaction":[[2008,1000.23],[2009,1200.34]],
"subscriber":[[2008,10000],[2009,12000]],
"business":[[2008,1000],[2009,1200]]}
```

I am coding in java and below is the code to fetch Cassandra rows

```
JavaRDD<CassandraRow> cassandraRDD = javaFunctions(sc).cassandraTable("test", "data_by_country");
```

What should be done to further aggregate the data

Comment: someone has voted down the question. Could i know if something is not correct

Comment: it's not me, but maybe because you haven't shared what you have tried and also because the low quality of the question.

Comment: @eliasah I have edited the post